# Error: Salesforce sandbox deployment

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I tried deploying the sandbox into Salesforce production but getting some errors. Also is it possible to make changes to the production code without the sandbox? Can someone also explain the code coverage? I tried changing that error field for the insert several times in the sandbox, But when I try to deploy it again, it still throws the same errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that your test class is trying to insert an opportunity record without filling mandatory field Close Date. Please check your code again. If you need any help please share the snippet of the code.

And yes you can make changes to Production directly, I wouldn't recommend that. Moving changes from sandbox to production after necessary testing is an ideal way of deploying new/existing changes. It's part of SDLC practice.